# Java: How to create & write file to maven target directory

Tags: java, file-io, path

Goal: 
Trying to create, and write text file to target folder in maven project

Method:

```
public synchronized void writeToFile(List<String> list, String file) {
        String path = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

        try {
            Path out = Paths.get( path + file);
            Files.write(out, list, Charset.defaultCharset());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Problems:

- java.nio.file.InvalidPathException error
- App will be deployed on different systems so path may change
- I don't know how to return the target path for this case without retrieving this error

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/Users/jquinn/IdeaProjects/Exercise1/Word%20Scraper%20-%20Java/target/classes/exclusions.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at FileManager.writeToFile(FileManager.java:58)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:21)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first `/` was causing a problem in the string. You have to get the full string without that.

I have tried with my class to achieve it :

```
String path = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
path = path.substring(1, path.length()) + "file.txt";
System.out.println(path);
Path out = Paths.get(path);
System.out.println(out.isAbsolute());
```

Output :

```
F:/software/workspace/file.txt
true
```

Comment: @Josh Quinn can you mark it as the verified answer ?

Answer (score -1):

Just use this

```
String pathTemp=System.getProperty("user.dir"); //it will give the root directory of where your program runs

String pathTemp=pathTemp+"/target/"+fileName; //here file name from the argument

Path path=Paths.get(pathTemp);

Files.write(path,list,Charset.defaultCharset());
```